# How to set Angular event binding statement in the code instead of doing in the template?

Tags: angular

Is there a way to set the event binding statement in the code (not in the template)?

I want to build a menu dynamically, I could do this with routes (since they are strings), but not with event names.

This is an example what I want to do:

component.ts code:

```js
menuItems = [
    { title: 'Invite Users', icon: 'account-multiple-plus', clickEvent: 'invite()' },
    { title: 'Users', icon: 'account-multiple', clickEvent: 'showUsers()' },
    { title: 'Log out', icon: 'settings', clickEvent: 'logout()' },
  ];
```

and component.html:

```html
        <ng-template let-item let-last="last" ngFor [ngForOf]="menuItems">
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="item.clickEvent">
            <mat-icon svgIcon="{{item.icon}}"></mat-icon>
            <span>{{item.title}}</span>
          </button>
        </ng-template>
```

It doesn't work. I guess I'd need to evaluate the variable item.click instead to use it as a literal. Is there a solution or an alternative for it?

Answer (score 5):

The way angular sees it, you are just binding a string, not an event.

You can do the following, replace

```
menuItems = [
    { title: 'Invite Users', icon: 'account-multiple-plus', clickEvent: 'invite()' },
    { title: 'Users', icon: 'account-multiple', clickEvent: 'showUsers()' },
    { title: 'Log out', icon: 'settings', clickEvent: 'logout()' },
];
```

with

```
menuItems = [
    { title: 'Invite Users', icon: 'account-multiple-plus', clickEvent: this.invite },
    { title: 'Users', icon: 'account-multiple', clickEvent: this.showUsers },
    { title: 'Log out', icon: 'settings', clickEvent: this.logout },
];
```

Now you have the actual function to be fired when clicked, not just a string.

And from your template:

```
 <button mat-menu-item (click)="item.clickEvent()">
```

Comment: Thank you @AlejandroCamba, it worked. The only thing I changed was to add ".bind(this)" in the array, I mean,  "this.logout.bind(this)" in order to keep the original scope.

Answer (score 1):

This way worked for me.

```js
menuItems = [
    { title: 'Invite Users', icon: 'account-multiple-plus', clickEvent: () => this.invite() },
    { title: 'Users', icon: 'account-multiple', clickEvent: () => this.showUsers() },
    { title: 'Log out', icon: 'settings', clickEvent: () => this.logout() },
];
```